# How to create a table to store playing cards and interact with them c++?

Tags: c++

How can I make an table of sorts to store playing cards.
For example in the image I have entered in the console a sequence "4cKs4h8s7sAd4s", one cards is each 2 digits, so 4c is four of clubs, Ks is kings of spades, etc. So I want to make something that can sort them in the way it shows in the image. And to be able to later count how many cards are 4, or how many cards are clubs. For now I'm storing it in a string and trying to match them with each other with for loop, but this didn't work as planed.
And this one table corresponds to one hand, so I would need to make 2 tables if there would be another sequence of cards or even more.

I hope that someone can understand what I meant. And I'm sorry if I misspelled some words.
I'm not asking for someone to write the code for me, although that would be great if someone could give some code. But atleast the basic idea of what I need to do.

I also tried to make a card class, and assign suit and rank to each card, but this doesn't let me count the cards if there are more than one sequence.

Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWJDI.jpg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>


unsigned int countWordsInString(std::string const& str)
{
    std::stringstream stream(str);
    return std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
}


class card{
    public:
        char rank;
        char suit;
        
        
        char addrank_suit(char InRank, char InSuit){
            rank = InRank;
            suit = InSuit;
        }
        

};


int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::stringstream b,c;
    
    std::cout << "Hand input" << std::endl;
    std::getline(std::cin,a);
    
    int wordcount;
    wordcount = countWordsInString(a);
    b << a;
    
    std::string *hand = new std::string[wordcount];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < wordcount ; i++){
        b >> hand[i];
    }
    
    //Makes the first 5 cards to form a board;
    card* Board = new card[5];
    Board[1].addrank_suit(hand[0][0],hand[0][1]), Board[2].addrank_suit(hand[0][2],hand[0][3]), Board[3].addrank_suit(hand[0][4],hand[0][5]);
    Board[4].addrank_suit(hand[0][6],hand[0][7]), Board[5].addrank_suit(hand[0][8],hand[0][9]);
    
    //4cKs4h8s7s Ad4s Ac4d As9s KhKd 5d6d 
        
    
    int handsize = wordcount - 1; 
    
    card* HandC = new card[handsize];
    
    //makes cards from the 4 digits, so one person has 2 cards
    int ii = 1;
    int iii = 2;
    int iiii = 1;
    do{
        HandC[iiii].addrank_suit(hand[ii][0],hand[ii][1]);
        HandC[iii].addrank_suit(hand[ii][2],hand[ii][3]);
        
        
        ii++;
        iiii = iiii + 2;
        iii = iii + 2;
    }while(ii < wordcount );

    //Checks for the same rank and suit cards
    //But doesn't include the cards from the board. 
    
    int check1 = 0;
    int check2 = 0;
    int check3 = 0;
    int check4 = 0;
    int han = 1;
    int han2 = 2;
    int loop = 1;
    do{
    
    
    for(int ch = 1; ch < wordcount ; ch++){
        if(HandC[han].rank == Board[ch].rank){
            check1++;
        }
    }
    for(int ch2 = 1; ch2<wordcount; ch2++){
        if(HandC[han2].rank == Board[ch2].rank){
            check2++;
        }
    }
    for(int ch3 = 1; ch3<wordcount; ch3++){
        if(HandC[han].suit == Board[ch3].suit){
            check3++;
        }
    }
    for(int ch4 = 1; ch4 < wordcount; ch4++){
        if(HandC[han2].suit == Board[ch4].suit){
            check4++;
        }
    }
    
    //for debug.
    std::cout << "Check1: " << check1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Check2: " << check2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Check3: " << check3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Check4: " << check4 << std::endl << std::endl;   
    //incomplete check for cominations, because this way it doesn't include the board cards.
    if(check1 == 1 && check2 == 1 && HandC[han].rank != HandC[han2].rank) {
        std::cout << "TWO Pair" << std::endl;
    }else if(check1 == 2 || check2 == 2 || check1 == 1 && check2 == 1){
        std::cout << "THREE OF A KIND" << std::endl;
    }else if(check1 == 3 || check2 == 3){
        std::cout << "Four of a kind" << std::endl;
    }else if(check1 == 1 )
    
    check1 = 0;
    check2 = 0;
    check3 = 0;
    check4 = 0;
    han = han + 2;
    han2 = han2 + 2;
    loop++;
    
}while(loop < wordcount);


    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I want to remake the whole thing to store them like it is in the image. Because this way doesn't check for board cards. And there would be too many loops and if statements to go through everything.

Comment: Can you show the program you've already written, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results? You have to show your work first; it must meet all requirements for a [mre]; and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your program and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Comment: Why use a table?  Most applications dealing with cards and decks define a `Card` class that has the suit and value.  A `Deck` would be a container of `Card`, such as `std::vector<Deck>`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I thought that in that kind of a table it would be easier to check for patterns, to make combination

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a table, here is one version.

### 2D Array Table

```
enum Card_Suit
{
    HEARTS, SPADES, DIAMONDS, CLUBS,
    MAX_SUITS
};

enum Card_Values
{
  ACE   =  1,
  JACK  = 11,
  QUEEN = 12,
  KING  = 13,
  MAXIMUM_COLUMNS
};

bool Card_Table[MAXIMUM_SUITS][MAXIMUM_COLUMNS];
```

The above definitions allow you to do something like:

```
  Card_Table[HEARTS][KING] = true;
```

You should search the internet for "c++ typedef 2d array" to create a synonym for the 2D array (which helps when passing to functions).

### 2D Vector Table

Another method is to use a 2d Vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> Card_Table_Vector;
```

### Converting Suit Letters to Numbers

Since you know how to use arrays, you can use an array to convert the suit letter to the table row index.

```
static const char suit_letter_to_index[] = {'h', 's', 'd', 'c'};
```

Search the array.  The index of the letter in the above array is the Suit value (row in the 2D table).

You can be more type consistent and friendly by using the enums with a `std::map`:

```
std::map<char, Card_Suit> letter_to_suit_enum;
letter_to_suit_enum['h'] = HEARTS;
letter_to_suit_enum['s'] = SPADES;
letter_to_suit_enum['d'] = DIAMONDS;
letter_to_suit_enum['c'] = CLUBS;
```

Example usage:

```
char suit_letter = 's';
Card_Suit suit = letter_to_suit_enum[suit_letter];
Card_Table[suit][QUEEN] = true;
```